# Xcode warning - Implicit conversion from enumeration type

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am seeing the warning error in Xcode as "Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum NSUITableViewRowAnimation' to different enumeration type 'UITableViewScrollPosition'

Here's the code where i am getting the error:

```
  [detailTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewRowAnimationTop animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all.  You aren't using the proper enumeration type.

You should be using `UITableViewScrollPositionTop`.

Reference: [Table View Scroll Position](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW7)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and reference link.